Laravel в Docker контейнере - настройка пользователей и прав на директории и файлы для PHP и NGINX контейнеров

Никак не могу найти инструкцию как все таки правильно настраивать пользователя под которым должен запускаться PHP и NGINX в контейнерах, что бы при этом пользователь на хост-системе имел права на директории и файлы xwr и не было никаких проблем ни в контейнере ни на хосте (при чтении, редактировании, создании).
Смотрел разные инструкции по добавлению проекта в Docker но везде этот момент пропущен, и по итогу у меня PHP создает директории с правами
xwr только для владельца, в следствии чего NGINX (или Laravel) отдают 404 при обращении к файлам в этих директориях.
NGINX: docker/images/nginx/Dockerfile
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html/public

PHP: docker/images/php/Dockerfile
RUN usermod -u 1000 -a -G www-data www-data

USER www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/html

docker-compose.yml
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/images/nginx
    volumes:
      - './docker/images/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro'
      - './docker/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx'
      - './source:/var/www/html'
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - php

  php:
    build:
      context: docker/images/php
    user: '1000:33'
    volumes:
      - './source:/var/www/html'
      - './docker/logs/php:/var/log/php/'

Вот при таких конфигурациях для контейнеров с nginx и php, у меня Laravel создает директорию с такими правами и владельцами
drwx------ 3 www-data  www-data 4096 дек 17 22:10 upload

при этом файлы в этой директории, создаются с такими правами
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 17782 дек 17 22:10 sddefault.jpg

Директорию и картинки создаю методом
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::put

Как все сделать правильно, что бы не было этих проблем с чтением, записью и исполнением файлов, поделитесь своими вариантами пожалуйста!

Еще я выяснил что нативный метод PHP mkdir создает таки деректории с нормальными правами для чтения drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 19 19:54 upload Не понимаю в чем тут дело, в методе  Storage::put третьим аргументом добавил 'public' но это не помогло...

Проблема решилась так:
для сервисов PHP и NGINX в docker-compos.yml добавил маппинг UID с хоста в конетйнер user: '1000:1000'
services:
  # Web service
  nginx:
    container_name: pod_nginx
    build:
      context: docker/images/nginx
    user: '1000:1000'
...
  # PHP service
  php:
    container_name: podvoh_tv_php
    build:
      context: docker/images/php
    user: '1000:1000'

Убрал из Dockerfile обеих сервисов
RUN usermod ...

и для сервиса NGINX заменил базовый образ на
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged

перезагрузил контейнеры, запустил создание директории тем же методом фреймворка, ничего не поменялось, права остались те же (только для владельца), но при этом через браузер файлы стали отдаваться 200!

вывод: проблемы были с тем что NGINX работал не под тем же пользователем что и PHP и не мог прочесть файлы?

Оптимально, чтобы в итоге номера пользоваелей в разных контейнерах в итоге совпадали, тогда будет как будто он один.
Если образ собирается на той же машине, можно пробросить аргумент:
RUN useradd --uid $C4UID ... и
docker build --build-arg C4UID=$(id -u) ...
Можно задавать USER ... для запуска.
Можно просто посмотреть в докерфайлы и сделать из 2-х один попробовать.
Если хост винда -- C4UUID=1000, но могут быть глюки всё равно.
